# Drop-down list in a table header

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a Drop-down list in table header, that will be triggered when you click on image which is in the table header.

**What I've tried:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $('#logo').click(function(){
           $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
       });

       $(document).click(function(e) {
           var target = e.target;
           if (!$(target).is('.dropdown-toggle') && !$(target).parents().is('.dropdown-toggle')) {
               $('.dropdown').show();
           }
       });

   });
</script>
```

Kindly give suggestions